# CN1-Charts - Loading time issue

Tags: codenameone

I am wondering if anybody has used the codename one charting library at
CN1-Charts

https://github.com/shannah/CN1-Charts

Its taking about 16 seconds for the app to build a basic bar chart on my Galaxy Note.

I pasted two libraries CN1Charts.cn1lib and CN1JSLib.cn1lib into the lib folder.

Did a right click refresh libs.

Code for building chart:

```
private void showChart() {
    Form f = new Form();
    final Label l = new Label("Loading Chart....pls wait");
    f.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    ChartBuilder b = new ChartBuilder();
    Chart chart = b.newBarChart(
            new double[][]{
                {1, 3, 2, 5},
                {3, 1, 2, 4},
                {7, 4, 1, 6},
                {2, 3, 4, 1}
            },
            new String[]{"BC", "Alberta", "Ontario", "Saskatchewan"},
            new String[]{"June", "July", "August", "Sept"}
    );
    ChartView v = new ChartView(chart);
    v.initLater(new Runnable() {

        public void run() {
            l.setText("Chart loaded!");

        }
    });

    Command back = new Command("Back") {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
            feed_form.showBack();
        }

    };
    f.setBackCommand(back);

    f.addComponent(BorderLayout.CENTER, v);
    f.addComponent(BorderLayout.NORTH, l);
    f.show();

}
```

Am i doing some wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code looks fine to me.  It is pretty close to the example app code https://github.com/shannah/CN1-Charts-Sample-App/blob/master/src/com/mycompany/myapp/MyApplication.java

And this example builds in milliseconds on iPhone 4s and nexus 7.

Do you get the same performance with the sample app code exactly?

Steve

Comment: Hi Steve, Thanks for your reply. I have tried the sample app on the same phone. The performance is similar (14 seconds this time). There were instances when the graph didn't event load. The same app works fabulously in the emulator.

Comment: I have made some changes now that should improve performance.  Try downloading the latest.
https://github.com/shannah/CN1-Charts/raw/master/dist/CN1Charts.cn1lib